# Uso do module-info.java

Tags: java, java-9

Quando o Eclipse cria um `module-info.java` o que seria?

Como eu devo empregar? Nos locais onde procuro nada está sintetizado.

Comment: Isso faz parte da definição de módulos do Java 9, introduzido no que foi chamado de Jigsaw. Nunca usei Java 9, mas estou estudando para poder dar uma resposta aqui. Enquanto isso, achei esse artigo do Baeldung que é uma boa leitura, inclusive de outra pessoa quiser escrever uma resposta enquanto não escrevo a minha: https://www.baeldung.com/project-jigsaw-java-modularity